# How can I keep the fields in an invalid form using PHP?

Tags: php, forms

I'm using PHP for form validation. If the form is invalid, I want to keep the existing values in all of the inputs, textareas, and 's. The form's action is the same page as the form itself, eg:

```
<form action= method=post>
...
</form>
```

Is there a way to keep the values of the fields other than echoing the values in every field?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a way to keep the values of the fields other than echoing the values in every field?

No, there isn't.

This is why it is generally a good idea to have a routine that templates your fields.

Comment: What do you mean by "a routine that templates your fields"?

Comment: @Linksku — a function (e.g. `textInput`) that takes a label, name, id, default value, optional current value and optional error message then outputs a chuck of HTML to represent it. It saves retyping near identical elements over and over. You could pull the current value directly from `$_GET/$_POST` if you want.

Answer (score 0):

There is a technique used by [`httpfill`](http://www.formencode.org/en/latest/htmlfill.html), which is part of the `FormEncode` Python form generation and validation library.

Basically, take your form html plus a data structure containing your values, parse your form html looking for form elements which correspond to items in your data structure, and add the value.

This doesn't take care of errors, but it can be extended to do so as `httpfill` has done. (It has a very simple system of special elements that are stripped out if there are no errors.)

But really, you should just template your fields as @Quentin says.